# Testing Form Data in phonegap/cordova

Tags: cordova, testing

I am totally a newbie to phonegap/cordova application. Basically i have a form in my application and i want to write a  script which basically enters the values in the form and keep on doing it with new random values everytime . I have no idea where to begin with . Can somebody please help me with this , so i can atleast start learning how to write automated testing script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically you can just take a function like this (by user [csharptest.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1349426/1744702))

```
function makeString()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    var len = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    for( var i=0; i < len; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
```

to get random strings. Then you do something like

```
document.getElementById("form_field1").value = makeString();
document.getElementById("form_field2").value = makeString();
```

for each of your fields of your form such as

```
<form id="my_form">
    <input type="text" id="form_field1" />
    <input type="text" id="form_field2" />
</form>
```

After setting the values, you can submit the form with

```
document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
```